# Microsoft Test Professional 2013 can't open .net projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I recently got a copy of Microsoft Test Professional 2013, where previously I used Visual Studio 2012. I'm unable to run any projects within Visual Studio 2013 - Shell Integrated, which comes with Test Professional 2013.

The development team have upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 with no issues and we have tried changing the project versions.

I have checked that I have the correct .net framework and mvc installed.

Should I be able to open the projects and if so what might be going wrong?